# How to check if a file exists in perforce in perl script

Tags: perl, perforce

I can use the `if (-e $file)` in perl script to tell if a file exists in linux or not.
I can run `p4 fstat $file` in linux to tell if a file exists in perforce depot.
But how do I use perl script to check if a file is in perforce depot?

Comment: How does the `p4` command signal the existence? Using backticks or [system](http://p3rl.org/system) should work.

Answer (score 4):

You can run a command from a Perl script with the backtick operator:

```
`p4 files $file`
```

This will work as a truthy check to see if a file exists in Perforce:

```
if (`p4 -F %depotFile% files "$file"`)
```

Note that this requires you to be logged in to the Perforce server before you run the script (if you can't connect you'll always get "false" from the above condition).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question asked, it appears that you could run the p4 command using Perl's `system()`, or the `exec()` method, or as described above using the "backticks" operator.

The backtics operator will allow you trap `STDERR` and `STDOUT` from the command, so that you can use it for whatever.

The other two will attempt run the command and give return values accordingly, as described in [perldoc -f exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html)

So, typically what can be done is a command like:

```
p4 files $file
```

Followed by

```
echo $?
```

The second command will get you the exit status of the last shell command.

When using backticks you can also try these:

Windows: `command-to-execute 2>NUL`

Linux / OSX: `command-to-execute 2> /dev/null`

These will suppress `STDERR` and give you the output only. If you use a "1" instead of a "2" you will suppress `STDOUT` and get the error only.

Finally, if you want both, you can use:

Windows / Linux / macOS: `command-to-execute 1>2&`

This will concatenate `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

So in short, you use Perl to run any existing program on any operating system, and there are multiple ways to process the result of that.